# Hostname in task error Undefined. How to reference nested element in dictionary value?

Tags: ansible

I have been trying multiple approaches to resolve this but I cannot figure out exactly what the problem is. I have a task in a simple playbook that is failing with the error `fatal: [CEASF-RTR]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'CEASF' is undefined"}` for the first host it runs on, thus it does not proceed to the next 2 tasks that do the same thing but on different hosts. I have checked my Interfaces yaml file and my inventory file and it all looks correct. The only thing I can think of is that I am not correctly referencing the dictionary key-value subelements in my task     `- name: "10020 - ADD NEW DHCP HELPER ADDRESS TO INTERFACES"`. I want to get the items under each hostname key-value to have the interfaces be the items to be applied to the command, like this:

```
CEASF-RTR:
  wired_dhcp_interfaces:
    - "GigabitEthernet0/0.1"
    - "GigabitEthernet0/0.4"
    - "GigabitEthernet0/0.5"
```

...but not sure how to do that. Also, the hostnames have dashes in them, could this be the problem as to why I am getting the Undefined error?

Thanks in advance.

Playbook error showing that the hostname is undefined:

```
TASK [10020 - ADD NEW DHCP HELPER ADDRESS TO INTERFACES] *******************************************************************************Thursday 20 April 2023  03:27:17 -0500 (0:00:01.598)       0:00:09.019 ********
fatal: [CEASF-RTR]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'CEASF' is undefined"}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************CEASF-RTR                  : ok=6    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

Thursday 20 April 2023  03:27:17 -0500 (0:00:00.104)       0:00:09.123 ********
===============================================================================
1010 - GATHER FACTS USING 'ios_facts` MODULE ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 5.50s
1030 - 'show ip interface brief' AND REGISTER TO 'interface_check' VAR ---------------------------------------------------------- 1.60s
10001 - INCLUDE INTERFACES VARS FROM FILE --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 0.67s
1020 - VALIDATE THIS IS NOT A 4K ROUTER ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 0.60s
10002 - INCLUDE IP HELPERS VARS FROM FILE --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 0.53s
10020 - ADD NEW DHCP HELPER ADDRESS TO INTERFACES ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 0.10s
10010 - RUN 'tasks/router_and_int_checks.yml' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 0.08s
Playbook run took 0 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes, 9 seconds
```

Inventory file referenced in Ansible.cfg:

```
[all:vars]
ansible_connection=network_cli
host_domain=*REDACTEDFORPRIVACY*
ansible_host='{{ inventory_hostname }}.{{ host_domain }}'

[ios:vars]
ansible_become=yes
ansible_become_method=enable
ansible_network_os=ios
net_platform=cisco_ios_ssh


[CEASF]
CEASF-RTR

[CO311CORE]
cowfm-311-core

[CEAMW]
CEAMW-RTR

[CESZP]
CESZP-RTR

[CE400]
ce400-rtr

[CO601CORE]
10.254.3.7

[CEGTK]
CEGTK-RTR

[CO828CORE]
cowfm-828-core


[ios:children]
CEASF
CO311CORE
CEAMW
CESZP
CESZP
CE400
CO601CORE
CEGTK
CO828CORE
```

Interfaces file:

```
---

CEASF-RTR:
  wired_dhcp_interfaces:
    - "GigabitEthernet0/0.1"
    - "GigabitEthernet0/0.4"
    - "GigabitEthernet0/0.5"
cowfm-311-core:
  wired_dhcp_interfaces:
    - "Vlan1"
    - "Vlan98"
    - "Vlan100"
    - "Vlan102"
    - "Vlan104"
cowfm-828-core:
  wired_dhcp_interfaces:
    - "Vlan1"
    - "Vlan172"
    - "Vlan174"
CEAMW-RTR:
  wired_dhcp_interfaces:
    - "GigabitEthernet0/0/0.1"
    - "GigabitEthernet0/0/0.2"
    - "GigabitEthernet0/0/0.3"
    - "GigabitEthernet0/0/0.4"
    - "GigabitEthernet0/0/0.5"
CESZP-RTR:
  wired_dhcp_interfaces:
    - "GigabitEthernet0/0.1"
    - "GigabitEthernet0/0.2"
    - "GigabitEthernet0/0.3"
    - "GigabitEthernet0/0.4"
    - "GigabitEthernet0/0.5"
ce400-rtr:
  wired_dhcp_interfaces:
    - "Vlan3"
    - "Vlan205"
    - "Vlan206"
10.254.3.7:
  wired_dhcp_interfaces:
    - "Vlan1"
    - "Vlan73"
    - "Vlan74"
    - "Vlan75"
    - "Vlan76"
    - "Vlan77"
CEGTK-RTR:
  wired_dhcp_interfaces:
    - "GigabitEthernet0/0.1"
    - "GigabitEthernet0/0.2"
    - "GigabitEthernet0/0.3"
    - "GigabitEthernet0/0.4"
    - "GigabitEthernet0/0.5"
...
```

Ansible.cfg file:

```
[defaults]
# inventory = ./rtr_inventory
inventory = ./ce_campus_rtr_inventory_singular
host_key_checking = False
forks = 10
retry_files_save_path = ../retry-files
ask_pass = True
become_ask_pass = True
callback_whitelist = profile_tasks, timer
timeout = 20
retries = 3

[inventory]
enable_plugins = yaml, ini
```

Playbook for updating IP helpers addresses:

```
---
- name: "10000 - ADD NEW DHCP HELPER ON SUBNETS"
  hosts: ios
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - name: "10001 - INCLUDE INTERFACES VARS FROM FILE"
      include_vars: ./vars/ce_campus_interfaces.yml

    - name: "10002 - INCLUDE IP HELPERS VARS FROM FILE"
      include_vars: ./vars/ip_helpers.yml

    - name: "10010 - RUN 'tasks/router_and_int_checks.yml'"
      include_tasks: "./tasks/router_and_int_check.yml"

    - name: "10020 - ADD NEW DHCP HELPER ADDRESS TO INTERFACES"
      delegate_to: CEASF-RTR
      ios_config:
        lines:
          - ip helper-address {{ wired_dhcp_server_1 }}
          - ip helper-address {{ wired_dhcp_server_2 }}
          - ip helper-address {{ wired_new_dhcp_server }}
        parents: interface {{ item }}
        diff_against: running
      with_items: "{{ CEASF-RTR.wired_dhcp_interfaces }}"
      when: 
        - 'item in interface_check.stdout[0]'
        - 'inventory_hostname in ansible_play_hosts'
        - "inventory_hostname == 'CEASF-RTR'"

    - name: "10020 - ADD NEW DHCP HELPER ADDRESS TO INTERFACES"
      delegate_to: cowfm-311-core
      ios_config:
        lines:
          - ip helper-address {{ wired_dhcp_server_1 }}
          - ip helper-address {{ wired_dhcp_server_2 }}
          - ip helper-address {{ wired_new_dhcp_server }}
        parents: interface {{ item }}
        diff_against: running
      with_items: "{{ cowfm-311-core.wired_dhcp_interfaces }}"
      when: 
        - 'item in interface_check.stdout[0]'
        - 'inventory_hostname in ansible_play_hosts'
        - "inventory_hostname == 'cowfm-311-core'"

    - name: "10020 - ADD NEW DHCP HELPER ADDRESS TO INTERFACES"
      delegate_to: CEAMW-RTR
      ios_config:
        lines:
          - ip helper-address {{ wired_dhcp_server_1 }}
          - ip helper-address {{ wired_dhcp_server_2 }}
          - ip helper-address {{ wired_new_dhcp_server }}
        parents: interface {{ item }}
        diff_against: running
      with_items: "{{ CEAMW-RTR.wired_dhcp_interfaces }}"
      when: 
        - 'item in interface_check.stdout[0]'
        - 'inventory_hostname in ansible_play_hosts'
        - "inventory_hostname == 'CEAMW-RTR'"

    - name: "10030 - SAVE THE CONFIGURATION IF IT WAS CHANGED"
      ios_config:
        save_when: modified
```

Comment: The problem is that `-` is not a valid character inside a variable name so you cannot reference the variable `CEASF-RTR` as is. When your write `{{ CEASF-RTR.wired_dhcp_interfaces }}`, ansible reads "substract `RTR.wired_dhcp_interfaces` from `CEASF`". The easiest way here would be to rename those vars and use underscores. Else you will have to go through the [`vars` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/vars_lookup.html) or use the bracket notation with some workarround (e.g. `{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['CEASF-RTR'].wired_dhcp_interfaces }}`)

Comment: Is there an ansible doc reference I can read on converting dashes to underscores in vars?

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#creating-valid-variable-names

Comment: Meanwhile, this all looks like an [x/y problem](https://xyproblem.info). There is no need to reference those hostnames as var names, nor to include any interface files if you move those definition directly inside your inventory.

Comment: I am not too keen on ansible yet, still have much to learn. Can you elaborate by what you mean when you say no need to ref hostnames as var names and move the definitions directly into my inventory so that it is not an x/y problem?

Comment: If you reference `wired_dhcp_interfaces` as a var for each group or each host in your inventory, you just have to call that variable

Comment: Okay, thanks. For the org, I am abiding by their guidelines, this is why I have an interfaces file and an inventory file.

Comment: As a simple example: https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/d200ea94e33ce7a39e653b692f3b7373 . Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: ***"The task is failing with the error:"***

```yaml
    - name: "10020 - ADD NEW DHCP HELPER ADDRESS TO INTERFACES"
      ...
      with_items: "{{ CEASF-RTR.wired_dhcp_interfaces }}"
```

> fatal: [CEASF-RTR]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'CEASF' is undefined"}

A: In Ansible, *CEASF-RTR* is not [valid variable name](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#creating-valid-variable-names). You can include the variable(s) in a dictionary

```yaml
    - name: "10001 - INCLUDE INTERFACES VARS FROM FILE"
      include_vars:
        file: vars/ce_campus_interfaces.yml
        name: ce_campus_interfaces
```

and use the [bracket notation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#referencing-key-value-dictionary-variables)

```yaml
    - name: "10020 - ADD NEW DHCP HELPER ADDRESS TO INTERFACES"
      ...
      loop: "{{ ce_campus_interfaces['CEASF-RTR'].wired_dhcp_interfaces }}"
```

Note: In YAML, the only restriction in a dictionary(mapping) is that each of the keys is unique.

See: Mapping [3.2.1.1. Nodes](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#3211-nodes)

---

[Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── playbook.yml
└── vars
    └── ce_campus_interfaces.yml

1 directory, 3 files
```

```ini
shell> cat ansible.cfg 
[defaults]
gathering = explicit
collections_path = $HOME/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/
retry_files_enabled = false
stdout_callback = yaml
```

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml 
---
- name: "10000 - ADD NEW DHCP HELPER ON SUBNETS"
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - name: "10001 - INCLUDE INTERFACES VARS FROM FILE"
      include_vars:
        file: vars/ce_campus_interfaces.yml
        name: ce_campus_interfaces

    - name: "10020 - ADD NEW DHCP HELPER ADDRESS TO INTERFACES"
      debug:
        msg: |-
          parents: interface {{ item }}
      loop: "{{ ce_campus_interfaces['CEASF-RTR'].wired_dhcp_interfaces }}"
```

```yaml
shell> cat vars/ce_campus_interfaces.yml 
---
CEASF-RTR:
  wired_dhcp_interfaces:
    - "GigabitEthernet0/0.1"
    - "GigabitEthernet0/0.4"
    - "GigabitEthernet0/0.5"
...
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml 
PLAY [10000 - ADD NEW DHCP HELPER ON SUBNETS] *************************************************

TASK [10001 - INCLUDE INTERFACES VARS FROM FILE] **********************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [10020 - ADD NEW DHCP HELPER ADDRESS TO INTERFACES] **************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=GigabitEthernet0/0.1) => 
  msg: 'parents: interface GigabitEthernet0/0.1'
ok: [localhost] => (item=GigabitEthernet0/0.4) => 
  msg: 'parents: interface GigabitEthernet0/0.4'
ok: [localhost] => (item=GigabitEthernet0/0.5) => 
  msg: 'parents: interface GigabitEthernet0/0.5'

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

**Use case:** Each host iterates a variable. The name of the variable is identical to the name of the host.

The project below

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── ce_campus_rtr_inventory_singular
├── playbook.yml
└── vars
    └── ce_campus_interfaces.yml

1 directory, 4 files
```

```ini
shell> cat ansible.cfg 
[defaults]
gathering = explicit
collections_path = $HOME/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/
retry_files_enabled = false
stdout_callback = yaml
```

```ini
shell> cat ce_campus_rtr_inventory_singular
[CEASF]
CEASF-RTR

[CO311CORE]
cowfm-311-core

[CEAMW]
CEAMW-RTR
```

```yaml
shell> cat vars/ce_campus_interfaces.yml
---
CEASF-RTR:
  wired_dhcp_interfaces:
    - "GigabitEthernet0/0.1"
    - "GigabitEthernet0/0.4"
    - "GigabitEthernet0/0.5"
cowfm-311-core:
  wired_dhcp_interfaces:
    - "Vlan1"
    - "Vlan98"
    - "Vlan100"
    - "Vlan102"
    - "Vlan104"
CEAMW-RTR:
  wired_dhcp_interfaces:
    - "GigabitEthernet0/0/0.1"
    - "GigabitEthernet0/0/0.2"
    - "GigabitEthernet0/0/0.3"
    - "GigabitEthernet0/0/0.4"
    - "GigabitEthernet0/0/0.5"
...
```

1. Substitute *inventory_hostname*

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml 
---
- name: "10000 - ADD NEW DHCP HELPER ON SUBNETS"
  hosts: all

  tasks:

    - name: "10001 - INCLUDE INTERFACES VARS FROM FILE"
      include_vars:
        file: vars/ce_campus_interfaces.yml
        name: ce_campus_interfaces
      run_once: true

    - name: "10020 - ADD NEW DHCP HELPER ADDRESS TO INTERFACES"
      debug:
        msg: |-
          parents: interface {{ item }}
      loop: "{{ ce_campus_interfaces[inventory_hostname].wired_dhcp_interfaces }}"
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i ce_campus_rtr_inventory_singular playbook.yml
PLAY [10000 - ADD NEW DHCP HELPER ON SUBNETS] *************************************************

TASK [10001 - INCLUDE INTERFACES VARS FROM FILE] **********************************************
ok: [CEASF-RTR]

TASK [10020 - ADD NEW DHCP HELPER ADDRESS TO INTERFACES] **************************************
ok: [CEASF-RTR] => (item=GigabitEthernet0/0.1) => 
  msg: 'parents: interface GigabitEthernet0/0.1'
ok: [CEASF-RTR] => (item=GigabitEthernet0/0.4) => 
  msg: 'parents: interface GigabitEthernet0/0.4'
ok: [cowfm-311-core] => (item=Vlan1) => 
  msg: 'parents: interface Vlan1'
ok: [CEASF-RTR] => (item=GigabitEthernet0/0.5) => 
  msg: 'parents: interface GigabitEthernet0/0.5'
ok: [cowfm-311-core] => (item=Vlan98) => 
  msg: 'parents: interface Vlan98'
ok: [CEAMW-RTR] => (item=GigabitEthernet0/0/0.1) => 
  msg: 'parents: interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0.1'
ok: [CEAMW-RTR] => (item=GigabitEthernet0/0/0.2) => 
  msg: 'parents: interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0.2'
ok: [cowfm-311-core] => (item=Vlan100) => 
  msg: 'parents: interface Vlan100'
ok: [CEAMW-RTR] => (item=GigabitEthernet0/0/0.3) => 
  msg: 'parents: interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0.3'
ok: [cowfm-311-core] => (item=Vlan102) => 
  msg: 'parents: interface Vlan102'
ok: [cowfm-311-core] => (item=Vlan104) => 
  msg: 'parents: interface Vlan104'
ok: [CEAMW-RTR] => (item=GigabitEthernet0/0/0.4) => 
  msg: 'parents: interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0.4'
ok: [CEAMW-RTR] => (item=GigabitEthernet0/0/0.5) => 
  msg: 'parents: interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0.5'

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
CEAMW-RTR: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
CEASF-RTR: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
cowfm-311-core: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

2. Brute force

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
---
- name: "10000 - ADD NEW DHCP HELPER ON SUBNETS"
  hosts: all

  tasks:

    - name: "10001 - INCLUDE INTERFACES VARS FROM FILE"
      include_vars:
        file: vars/ce_campus_interfaces.yml
        name: ce_campus_interfaces
      run_once: true

    - name: "10020 - ADD NEW DHCP HELPER ADDRESS TO INTERFACES"
      debug:
        msg: |
          parents: interface {{ item }}
      with_items: "{{ ce_campus_interfaces['CEASF-RTR'].wired_dhcp_interfaces }}"
      delegate_to: CEASF-RTR
      run_once: true

    - name: "10020 - ADD NEW DHCP HELPER ADDRESS TO INTERFACES"
      debug:
        msg: |
          parents: interface {{ item }}
      with_items: "{{ ce_campus_interfaces['cowfm-311-core'].wired_dhcp_interfaces }}"
      delegate_to: cowfm-311-core
      run_once: true

    - name: "10020 - ADD NEW DHCP HELPER ADDRESS TO INTERFACES"
      debug:
        msg: |
          parents: interface {{ item }}
      with_items: "{{ ce_campus_interfaces['CEAMW-RTR'].wired_dhcp_interfaces }}"
      delegate_to: CEAMW-RTR
      run_once: true
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i ce_campus_rtr_inventory_singular playbook.yml
PLAY [10000 - ADD NEW DHCP HELPER ON SUBNETS] *************************************************

TASK [10001 - INCLUDE INTERFACES VARS FROM FILE] **********************************************
ok: [CEASF-RTR]

TASK [10020 - ADD NEW DHCP HELPER ADDRESS TO INTERFACES] **************************************
ok: [CEASF-RTR] => (item=GigabitEthernet0/0.1) => 
  msg: |-
    parents: interface GigabitEthernet0/0.1
ok: [CEASF-RTR] => (item=GigabitEthernet0/0.4) => 
  msg: |-
    parents: interface GigabitEthernet0/0.4
ok: [CEASF-RTR] => (item=GigabitEthernet0/0.5) => 
  msg: |-
    parents: interface GigabitEthernet0/0.5

TASK [10020 - ADD NEW DHCP HELPER ADDRESS TO INTERFACES] **************************************
ok: [CEASF-RTR -> cowfm-311-core] => (item=Vlan1) => 
  msg: |-
    parents: interface Vlan1
ok: [CEASF-RTR -> cowfm-311-core] => (item=Vlan98) => 
  msg: |-
    parents: interface Vlan98
ok: [CEASF-RTR -> cowfm-311-core] => (item=Vlan100) => 
  msg: |-
    parents: interface Vlan100
ok: [CEASF-RTR -> cowfm-311-core] => (item=Vlan102) => 
  msg: |-
    parents: interface Vlan102
ok: [CEASF-RTR -> cowfm-311-core] => (item=Vlan104) => 
  msg: |-
    parents: interface Vlan104

TASK [10020 - ADD NEW DHCP HELPER ADDRESS TO INTERFACES] **************************************
ok: [CEASF-RTR -> CEAMW-RTR] => (item=GigabitEthernet0/0/0.1) => 
  msg: |-
    parents: interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0.1
ok: [CEASF-RTR -> CEAMW-RTR] => (item=GigabitEthernet0/0/0.2) => 
  msg: |-
    parents: interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0.2
ok: [CEASF-RTR -> CEAMW-RTR] => (item=GigabitEthernet0/0/0.3) => 
  msg: |-
    parents: interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0.3
ok: [CEASF-RTR -> CEAMW-RTR] => (item=GigabitEthernet0/0/0.4) => 
  msg: |-
    parents: interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0.4
ok: [CEASF-RTR -> CEAMW-RTR] => (item=GigabitEthernet0/0/0.5) => 
  msg: |-
    parents: interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0.5

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
CEASF-RTR: ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

3. Iterate with subelements

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
---
- name: "10000 - ADD NEW DHCP HELPER ON SUBNETS"
  hosts: all

  tasks:

    - name: "10001 - INCLUDE INTERFACES VARS FROM FILE"
      include_vars:
        file: vars/ce_campus_interfaces.yml
        name: ce_campus_interfaces
      run_once: true

    - name: "10020 - ADD NEW DHCP HELPER ADDRESS TO INTERFACES"
      debug:
        msg: |-
          parents: interface {{ item.1 }}
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ ce_campus_interfaces|dict2items }}"
        - value.wired_dhcp_interfaces
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.0.key }}"
      delegate_to: "{{ item.0.key }}"
      run_once: true
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i ce_campus_rtr_inventory_singular playbook.yml
PLAY [10000 - ADD NEW DHCP HELPER ON SUBNETS] *************************************************

TASK [10001 - INCLUDE INTERFACES VARS FROM FILE] **********************************************
ok: [CEASF-RTR]

TASK [10020 - ADD NEW DHCP HELPER ADDRESS TO INTERFACES] **************************************
ok: [CEASF-RTR] => (item=CEASF-RTR) => 
  msg: 'parents: interface GigabitEthernet0/0.1'
ok: [CEASF-RTR] => (item=CEASF-RTR) => 
  msg: 'parents: interface GigabitEthernet0/0.4'
ok: [CEASF-RTR] => (item=CEASF-RTR) => 
  msg: 'parents: interface GigabitEthernet0/0.5'
ok: [CEASF-RTR -> cowfm-311-core] => (item=cowfm-311-core) => 
  msg: 'parents: interface Vlan1'
ok: [CEASF-RTR -> cowfm-311-core] => (item=cowfm-311-core) => 
  msg: 'parents: interface Vlan98'
ok: [CEASF-RTR -> cowfm-311-core] => (item=cowfm-311-core) => 
  msg: 'parents: interface Vlan100'
ok: [CEASF-RTR -> cowfm-311-core] => (item=cowfm-311-core) => 
  msg: 'parents: interface Vlan102'
ok: [CEASF-RTR -> cowfm-311-core] => (item=cowfm-311-core) => 
  msg: 'parents: interface Vlan104'
ok: [CEASF-RTR -> CEAMW-RTR] => (item=CEAMW-RTR) => 
  msg: 'parents: interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0.1'
ok: [CEASF-RTR -> CEAMW-RTR] => (item=CEAMW-RTR) => 
  msg: 'parents: interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0.2'
ok: [CEASF-RTR -> CEAMW-RTR] => (item=CEAMW-RTR) => 
  msg: 'parents: interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0.3'
ok: [CEASF-RTR -> CEAMW-RTR] => (item=CEAMW-RTR) => 
  msg: 'parents: interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0.4'
ok: [CEASF-RTR -> CEAMW-RTR] => (item=CEAMW-RTR) => 
  msg: 'parents: interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0.5'

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
CEASF-RTR: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```